# Read multiple CSV files automatically from a directory inside a ForEach Controller with JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Im trying to read multiple CSV files from a special directory inside a While Controller to convert the data in the files to a specific JMeter property/variable. But I always get an error:

```
ERROR - jmeter.threads.JMeterThread: Test failed! java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: File ${CURRENTACTIONATTRIBUTEFILE} must exist and be readable
```

Is it possible that the variable isn't evaluated at this moment? (__V doesn't change anything).I really have no idea why this isn't working.

When I place a Debug Sampler between the ForEach and the While Controller it shows me the JMeterVariable CURRENTACTIONATTRIBUTEFILE has the correct path and file name (when I paste this string hardcoded in the CSV data set config filename it works):

```
CURRENTACTIONATTRIBUTEFILE=C:/#JMeter/Plans/PRODUCT/61_RISK2VALUE/61_RISK2VALUE - Resources/ModelingData/ActionAttributes/ActionAttributes_AM2.csv
```

This is what my Testplan Setup looks like:

- CREATE file variables: groovy sampler, which checks a special directory and creates numbered vars with the file path + name + extension and a var with the count of the files found in the directory
- [ForEach Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEtNi.png)

  - [While Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AZQs.png)

    - CSV Data Set Config *(Filename: ${CURRENTACTIONATTRIBUTEFILE)*
    - CREATE variables: groovy sampler, which creates properties/vars to a special convention I need

"CREATE file variables" - sampler code:

```
String actionAttributeFilePath = "${PATHPLAN}${PATHMODELINGDATA}ActionAttributes/";
File modelingDataDirectory = new File(actionAttributeFilePath);

File[] files = modelingDataDirectory.listFiles();
int fileCounter = 1;
for (File file : files) {
    if(file)
    {
        String actionAttributeFile = actionAttributeFilePath + file.getName();
         vars.put("ACTIONATTRIBUTEFILE_" + fileCounter, actionAttributeFile);
         fileCounter++;
    }
}
vars.put("ACTIONATTRIBUTEFILE_COUNT", Integer.toString(fileCounter-1))
```

"CREATE variables" - sampler code (not relevant for my problem):

All variables names used below, come from the CSV data set config.

```
if ("${ATTRIBUTEDEFINITIONID}" != "<EOF>")
{
    def variableName = sprintf('ATTRIBUTE%2$sDEFINITIONID_%1$s',["${ATTRIBUTEFORMULANAME}", "${ATTRIBUTETYPE}"])
    props.put(variableName,"${ATTRIBUTEDEFINITIONID}");
}
```

Comment: Dmitri T's answer showed me that this isn't possible. Therefore I'm trying to solve it without using a CSV read and read the CSV with a groovy script or similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to use a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) as a CSV Data Set Config filename as CSV Data Set Config is being initialized **before** any variables.

The only way to make this dynamic is using JMeter Property instead of JMeter Variable

1. Substitute your  `${CURRENTACTIONATTRIBUTEFILE}` variable reference with JMeter Property using [__P() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) as `${__P(CURRENTACTIONATTRIBUTEFILE,)}`
2. Provide the property value via `-J` command line argument like:

   ```
   jmeter -JCURRENTACTIONATTRIBUTEFILE="C:/#JMeter/Plans/PRODUCT/61_RISK2VALUE/61_RISK2VALUE - Resources/ModelingData/ActionAttributes/ActionAttributes_AM2.csv"
   ```

   Another way of setting the property is defining it in *user.properties* file like:

   ```
   CURRENTACTIONATTRIBUTEFILE="C:/#JMeter/Plans/PRODUCT/61_RISK2VALUE/61_RISK2VALUE - Resources/ModelingData/ActionAttributes/ActionAttributes_AM2.csv"
   ```

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Oh, that's bad! The solution with a argument or a user property isn't fitting for me, because I want it dynamically and completely automated. Therefore I'm trying to solve it without using a CSV read and read the CSV with a groovy script or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The CSV Data Set Config element has a field called `Filename` where you need to specify the file name of your CSV along with its' path.

By default JMeter starts to look for data files in the JMeter root/home folder (\apache-jmeter-x. xx\bin) or the same folder where the JMeter script (.jmx file) resides.

So you can have your `CSV` files together in the same directory than the .jmx.